# Laravel and Wordpress in same directory

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel

I have an existing Laravel project, which needs the home page in Wordpress.

Now the requirement is like, both setups (Laravel and Wordpress) should be in the same directory without creating any subdirectories.

I have merged both, and in Laravel's `index.php` file I have added code like

```
if(URL == "some home URL"){

define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-blog-header.php');

}
```

I know this is not the correct way to use it, but this is working fine only for the home page.

But, now if any blog URL, archive URL, search URL hits, the Wordpress page should be displayed.

I have gone through many stack articles but did not get the perfect solution for this.

Comment: You shoud add if conditions for all your specific wordpress url's eg:- archive, blogs etc

Comment: don't handle url's eg:- archive, blogs etc  from laravel end then may be it will be handle from wordpress